# How do I log out innactive users after 30 minutes?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to log out inactive users. If they have not moved the mouse or typed in 30 minutes then they are automatically logged out and returned to the login screen. The logon details are stored in my database.

The login routine

```
<?php
require_once('includes/session.php');
    if (isset($_GET['logout']) and $_GET['logout'] == 1){
        logout();
    }
    //doublecheck status
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $login = 1; $login_message = "Logged In";
    }else{
        $login = 0; $login_message = "Logged Out";
    }

include_once("../includes/masterinclude.php");
//include_once("../includes/functions_admin.php");


$preferences = getPreferences();
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $message_login = "";

    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $hashed_password = sha1($password);
        $u = Confirm_User($username, $hashed_password);
        if ($u == 1){
            $u = Get_User($username, $hashed_password);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $u->user_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $u->user_name;
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.location.href=\"/home\";</script>";
        }else{
            $warning = "red";
            $message_login = "Login failed - Please try again";
        }
    }
?><head>



<form id="login" name="login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="_cms/login.php" _cms/style="display: block;">
            <div class="form-group" id="reauthorizeInner">
                <?php
                if($message_login != ""){
                    echo "<p><span class=\"message-error\">" . $message_login . "</span></p>";
                }else{
                    echo "<p class=\"message\">Please enter your username &amp; password</p>";
                }
                ?>
                <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                    <input id="reauthuser" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username.." name="username" value="username" onFocus="this.value=''" required="yes" message="You must enter a username">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-fixed-width"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="reauthorizeInner">
                <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                    <input id="reauthPassword" class="form-control" name="password" type="password" value="password" onFocus="this.value=''" required="yes" message="You must enter a password">

                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="icon-asterisk icon-fixed-width"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" onclick="document['login'].submit();">
                        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="make-switch pull-left" data-on="primary" data-off="danger"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Session.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $login = 1;
}else{
    $login = 0;
}

function confirm_logged_in() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        //redirect
        header("Location: /_cms/login.php?login=0");
    }
}
function logout(){
        $_SESSION = array();
        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
        }   
        session_destroy();
}

?>
```

I know there is alot of code here but I have to include this otherwise people will not see the complexity of creating a logout timer for this. I have tried a few different methods and none of them work because of the way the login routine is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually logging in and out of a system is considered a security measure - but a security measure cannot be enforced client side. If you want to ensure that sessions are terminated you will need a custom session handler.

Answer (score 2):

I would use some JS/jQuery and [iddletimout library](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout) and combine it with your PHP code:

```
$.idleTimeout('#idletimeout', '#idletimeout a', {
        idleAfter: 300, //seconds
        onTimeout: function() {
           //some code
           window.location = "logout.php"; //This is your PHP logout page
        },
        onIdle: function() {
            //some code
        },
        onCountdown: function(counter) {
            //some code
        },
        onResume: function() {
            //some code
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay so if I was to bolt in my php. where would my login and logout function go into this? Sorry I am awful with JS. Could you explain what the onTimeout, onIdle, onCountdown, onResume do? Thanks :)

Comment: well an easy easy way to do it, is to create a php page that specifically is meant to log out. This page will kill the session and redirect the user to the homepage. Then in the JS, you will redirect the user to the logout page on timeout: `onTimeout: function() { window.location = "logout.php";}`

Comment: in order to understand the Iddletimeout functions better, you need to check out the link I provided for the documentation. Its either that, or make up your own JS, but why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Okay I will have a read now, thankyou very much for your help!

Comment: I have never done this before but do I download these files and put them on my server or..?

Comment: ah. Yes, for any libraries, you need to download them. Place them on your server, and include them in your html by using `<script>` tags. Once you do that, you can then use any variables in that library.

Comment: I have added these files. Do I simply include the JS files in my header and it will work then or will I have to do some work on them?

Comment: you include them in your header, and under that include the code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80796/discussion-between-jonlloyd-and-codegodie).

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865944/how-to-use-eric-hynds-idle-timeout-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need some JavaScript code which will count time and reset counter if some event happens. But if counter reach 30 minutes you'll have to do AJAX call which will log out that user - call that logout function of yours.

Comment: Why negative? Explain please.

Comment: I didn't make it negative!

Comment: neither did I. Some users are haters.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could just use PHP's built-in session time-out, which by default kills the session after 30 mins of no activity anyway.

If you want it to stay alive while the user is moving the mouse (as opposed to actively making http requests), then you could have some code in your Javascript that sends an ajax 'ping' event triggered every so often by the mouse moving. The ajax ping doesn't need to even do anything, as long as it runs a dummy PHP script that references the session it'll be enough keep the session open. If the ping script isn't called for 30 mins, then the session will time-out.

So theres no real need to specifically call a log-out; just let the session expire.

(you'll need to have this happen anyway, to handle cases where the user closes his browser, or it crashes, or he loses network connection, etc; you don't want the session hanging around forever in those cases)

Comment: " kills the session after 30 mins of no activity" - no the session becomes eligible for garbage collection after session.gc_maxlifetime seconds with no requests - the default session handler will happily continue to serve up sessions older than this until they get deleted.