# How to automatically logout and redirect user to the login page after 30 minutes of inactivity?

Tags: php

I have this script:

```
function logincheck(){
    session_start();
    if (($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) || isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
}
```

This script destroys the session after 30 minutes of inactivity but doesn't automatically redirect users to the login page, what I want to achieve is when the session is destroyed, it automatically redirects to `login.php` where users can log back in again. How can I do that ?

EDIT:

Perhaps using some kind of javascript ? I'm still learning about JS sorry

Comment: do you mean to automatically redirect even if a person hasn't done anything on the page, or whenever they try to do something?

Comment: when the person isn't doing anything after 30 minutes, and it's just not redirect but also destroy the session.

Comment: I got that part.    Do you want the page to do this upon user interaction, or to just detect that they haven't done anything and redirect on its own?

Comment: Yes do it automatically without any user interaction

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/30893801/ similar question. Might help.

Comment: okay, you'd need to reload the page.   try this (for every 5 minutes as an example) `header("Refresh: 300;url="Location: login.php");`  or use javascript to reload the page (or best, both)

Comment: This sounds like you'll want to use either Javascript like @nomistic said or a mix of JS/jQuery and Ajax which will allow you to set a timer for activity (JS/jQuery) and check the session time and destroy and redirect it (Ajax/PHP).

Comment: @Lin Put exit(); after  header("Location: login.php"); that might work.